# Node command refers to older version

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

Hello when I use the `node` command on my Mac. It refers to an older version:

```
-bash: /usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I have removed node 14 and later installed the latest version of node with `brew install node`.

How can I make that the `node` command refers to the latest version?

Comment: You can also simplify your life by using a node version manager like [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this issue can be uncovered by `brew doctor` run.

But like Andreas said, it should be resolved by `brew link --overwrite node` to fix the node symlink.

If you just need `node`, you can use `nvm` to manage the different node versions for different applications, and you can also use `.node-version` to specify this metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some invalid symlink pointing to the old version. Especially with version-specific packages, this can be the case. You might first check where your node executable is referenced from by running `which node` to make sure if the symlink comes from brew (usually using `/usr/local/bin/node`) and list the details of the link by e.g. `ls -la $(which node)`.

To fix the link to point to the package you want, you can run

`brew link node`

Maybe this requires some force...

`brew link --force node`.

For details check [this answer on apple stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207883/336997)